# record session for user not logged

Tags: session, symfony

I am using Symfony2.0 and I wonder if there is a way to "record" visitors through a kind of session.

The idea is: I have a website about questions. And you need to be logged for some questions, but I want to create a trial mode. The idea is that a visitor who comes, try the trial, and when she/he comes back later, still has the questions she/he played, saved. Her/his score will be saved as for other users.

Except that if we lost the session, it is not a problem. (Like if she/he resets the cookies, or we clean the trial database records)

The ideal situation is to store a session number in the database, and when a user come back, I check if he matches in the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I see here is cookies, but if the user enters from a different pc then you have nothing, you can provide a "user-like" experience but with limitations.

Save a cookie in the user browser, then create a session object but be sure to save it in a non-volatile way. It seems you would be fine implementing a session class specially for this, sounds fun.